# Spivak's Calculus for a soon to be physics undergraduate.

Tags: soft-question, advice

I'll soon start my undergrad. studies in physics and because of that I picked up Spivak's Calculus a while ago to get a solid foundation in single-variable calculus before I start my studies. However, I have read that a book such as Spivak's Calculus isn't a particularly good choice for a physics student - not that one doesn't learn useful stuff from it but simply because of the fact that that amount of mathematical rigorousness probably isn't neccesary for a physics student (at this time in my career) and my time would be spent more wisely with a different book more relevant to physics.
I've chosen to ask this question in the mathematics community too, since there probably are more of you who yourself have been through Spivak.

EDIT: In short, should I continue with Spivak or should I find a different book (perhaps entirely different subject) which is more relevant to physics?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear - Should I continue with Spivak or spend my time with a book more relevant to physics?

Comment: @Merkh .. Forgot to tag

Comment: As someone who majored in both physics and math, I found learning mathematical rigor greatly helped me in my physics studies.  Not because we "needed" it, but because it helps you develop a systematic way to work through difficult problems, you gain intuition, and plus, knowing more rigorous math will never hurt you in physics.  For that reason, Spivak is a good book for you if you don't feel completely lost reading it.  If you are getting nothing out of it, change to something easier, then go back to Spivak.

Comment: At what point in your studies did you go through Spivak? @Merkh

Comment: I went through it late in my studies (wouldn't recommend as the best way), after I knew the material from other books.  I made it well through differential equations, quantum physics, theoretical mechanics, etc. before I decided to go back and actually *learn* what calculus is, instead of just referring to calculus as a bunch of rules.  I think it would've been better had I gone through it earlier in my education.

Comment: I see. Would you recommend any supplementary book to Spivak? I've heard people speaking well of Apostol's, do you have any experience with that one? @Merkh

Comment: No, but if you really want to learn calculus to its fullest extent and how to think mathematically, Courant and John, Calc and Analysis Vol 1 is the book.  Its cheap as an amazon paperback, worth buying and not just having a pdf.

Comment: Yeah I've looked at the one by Courant recently - would you suggest going through Spivak first and then Courant, vice versa or perhaps simoultanously? @Merkh

Answer (score 1):

I have nothing but pleasant memories of my time with Spivak, and I am nostalgically delighted that he is still used.

To some extent it depends on you and your personal taste and temperament. Some people want nothing but a box of tools to memorise, along with instructions for which to pick when. Others aren't satisfied unless they know how things work — indeed, they can't understand unless they do know that.

I am more mathematically inclined because I am lazy, hate memorising and hate facts. This is a great saving in brain capacity because I can invent the bits of maths I need as and when I need them. If a result comes out as $ \frac{0}{0} $, I don't apply l'Hôpital's Rule, I take the limit as $x$ tends to 0 (which is, of course, the same thing but doesn't involve magic incantations).

*You need to know what style suits you best,* and only you can discover that. I would say, **try Spivak** and see how you get on. If he takes time proving rigorously that this or that thing works, and you aren't interested, skip. It's allowed: indeed, it's compulsory.

If it all gets too much for you, drop it and find something else. But you will probably find that a well-skipped Spivak does all you need. And it's good to get thinking in terms of first principles early on, because a first-principles approach will save you a great deal of effort in your physical studies as well.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. - At what point in your studies did you go through Spivak?